# using indexes in lists in an if statment

Tags: python

I am writing a code for class, and have gotten stuck. My troubleshooting is not helping me. The first problem I have is when splitting the read file into a [name,score] format for an index in a list, it reads extra lines but also the correct ones. Then when writing the outfile, it only reads the last index in the list, but for that index in the list, that is the correct output.  I have been reading my book but cant find how to use the list and its indexes to go through the second if statement. This is the assignment:
Write a program that will read an unknown number of bowlers and their bowling scores (with possible values from 1 to 300) from an external file called "bowlingscores.txt". The file will look similar to the following: David 102 Hector 300 Mary 195 Jane 160 Sam 210 Output the bowlers’ names to an external data file called "bowlingaverages.txt". Next to each bowler's name, print a message dependent on their scores: For perfect scores (equal to 300), output “perfect” For those scores greater than the average score, output “above average” For those below average, output “below average” Your program must include at least one function (e.g., to calculate the average, to determine the appropriate message to print, etc.).

```
infile = open("bowlingscores.txt", "r")
name=0
score=0
averagescore=0
count=0
bowlersinfo=[]
for line in infile:
    if line.strip().isdigit():
        score=int(line)
    else:
        name=line.strip()
    bowler= name, score
    bowlersinfo.append(bowler)
 print bowlersinfo
 averagescore += score
 infile.close()
 averagescore /= float(len(name))
 for count in range (len(name)):
     if score==300:
         outcome= "Perfect"
     elif score > averagescore:
         outcome= "Above Average"
     elif score== averagescore:
         outcome= "Average"
     else:
         outcome= "Below Average"
 outfile = open("bowlingaverages.txt", "w")
 outfile.write(name, ) 
 outfile.write(outcome)
 outfile.close()
 print ("%s, %0.0f, %s" % (name, float(score), outcome))
```

---

This is the output I am getting. The bold print is the output I need it to put out. not all the extra. and each name should show like the last line.
[('David', 0), **('David', 102)**, ('Hector', 102), **('Hector', 300)**, ('Mary', 300), **('Mary', 195)**, ('Jane', 195), **('Jane', 160)**, ('Sam', 160), **('Sam', 210)**]
**Sam, 210, Above Average**

Comment: calm down with that bold font there, don't scream at us.

Comment: We don't need the **assignment**, we need the **problem**.

Comment: A dictionary would be more helpful in this situation. Maybe you should look into that.

Comment: Sorry about the bold.  And my teacher told us she wanted a list format not dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am not sure if your looping structure is right and if you are reading the string correctly when you read the file.

I didn't want to mess with your original code too much. So I changed a few things here and there. You could make your code a lot more compact.

```
infile = open("bowlingscores.txt", "r")
name=0
score=0
averagescore=0
count=0
bowlersinfo=[]
for line in infile:
   bowler,score= line.split()
   score = int(score)
   averagescore += score
   bowlersinfo.append([bowler,score])
print (bowlersinfo)


infile.close()

averagescore /= float(len(bowlersinfo))

outfile = open("bowlingaverages.txt", "w")

for name,score in bowlersinfo:
 if score==300:
     outcome= "Perfect"
 elif score > averagescore:
     outcome= "Above Average"
 elif score== averagescore:
     outcome= "Average"
 else:
     outcome= "Below Average"
 print ("%s, %0.0f, %s" % (name, float(score), outcome))
 outfile.write(name+": " ) 
 outfile.write(outcome+"\n")
outfile.close()
```